# How to hide spring mvc web app name in the browser url?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I have a spring mvc 3.x web app in eclipse where the resource project artifact name is "webapp".  So, `http://localhost:8080/webapp` will load the main home page using tomcat 7 with the eclipse IDE.

However, when I release to tomcat 7.0 to some prod servers I don't want the URL to resolve to http://mywebsite.com/webapp but instead http://mywebsite.com

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow either of below approaches

1. Delete existing ROOT/ directory (in webapps) from tomcat and rename your war file to ROOT.war and then deploy it.
2. Configure the context root in tomcat's conf/server.xml to use your war file (assuming my_war is your war name)

   < Context path="" docBase="my_war" reloadable="true">

Comment: awesome. thanks! I noticed that I could change it in tomcat per modules within eclipse and set path from /mywebap to /.  I will definitely use number 2.  But just to be clear this is a change on tomcat correct? Is there a way to configure this before hand within my project somewhere then deploy the war file and have those path changes picked up?