# How remove context path in java application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, contextpath

I want to remove context path from my url. when i run project its run in `http:///localhost:8080/myApp/`. i want to remove myApp from it. 
all my config based on java. i change context.xml to this `<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/"/>` but when i want to login that based on spring security not working. I also add web.xml based java config like this.

```
     public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws   ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =   servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new   DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
  }

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("mypac.config");
    return context;
 }
}
```

Comment: what server you used? tomcat or jboss?

Comment: @ Ataur Rahman Munna my server is tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

For tomcat server, you can delete your existing ROOT/ directory.
Rename your war as `ROOT.war` and deploy it.

Configure the context root in tomcat's `conf/server.xml` to use your war file (assuming my_war is your war name)

```
< Context path="" docBase="my_war" reloadable="true">
```

you can follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072190/how-to-hide-spring-mvc-web-app-name-in-the-browser-url) also that already answered.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using Eclipse ide**:

1. Right click your project, choose `Properties`->`Web Project Settings`-> in Context root, change `yourApp` to `/` and click `OK`.
2. In `Servers Explorer`, remove `yourApp` from `Tomcat Server`.
3. **(Option)** If you use `Maven`, right click your project -> choose `Maven` -> choose `Update Project`.
4. Rerun your project.